# Color and Texture-Based Shadow Detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I'm doing a project on tracking and Object classification in video surveillance,and i have some difficulties with removing the shadows from the foreground objects.
The problem is that i can't just use any method that i want, i have to use the same method described in this article   [Shadow removal with blob based morphological reconstruction](http://www.iti.gr/SCHEMA/files/document/27-01-2005/icassp05_Shadow_Xu_Landabaso_Pardas.pdf) .

In the article they use a hybrid shadow removal method- RGB color based detection and texture based detection. Both the colour and texture based procedures are used in parallel, followed by an assertion process that combines the results of the two.

So i would like to get some help with the shadow removal Matlab code.

my code so far

```
function Tracking_Objects()

% Create System objects used for reading video, detecting moving objects,
% and displaying the results.
obj = setupSystemObjects();

tracks = initializeTracks(); % Create an empty array of tracks.

nextId = 1; % ID of the next track

% Detect moving objects, and track them across video frames.
while ~isDone(obj.reader)
    frame = readFrame();
    [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame);
    predictNewLocationsOfTracks();
    [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
        detectionToTrackAssignment();

    updateAssignedTracks();
    updateUnassignedTracks();
    deleteLostTracks();
    createNewTracks();

    displayTrackingResults();
end


%% Create System Objects

    function obj = setupSystemObjects()
        % Initialize Video I/O
        % Create objects for reading a video from a file, drawing the tracked
        % objects in each frame, and playing the video.

        % Create a video file reader.
        obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader('input.avi');

        % Create two video players, one to display the video,
        % and one to display the foreground mask.
        obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [10, 250, 700, 400]);
        obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [720, 250, 700, 400]);


        obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...
            'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);


        obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
            'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
            'MinimumBlobArea', 75);
    end

%% Initialize Tracks

     function tracks = initializeTracks()
        % create an empty array of tracks
        tracks = struct(...
            'id', {}, ...
            'bbox', {}, ...
            'kalmanFilter', {}, ...
            'age', {}, ...
            'totalVisibleCount', {}, ...
            'consecutiveInvisibleCount', {});
    end

%% Read a Video Frame
% Read the next video frame from the video file.
    function frame = readFrame()
        frame = obj.reader.step();
    end

%% Detect Objects

    function [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame)

        % Detect foreground.
        mask = obj.detector.step(frame);

        % Apply morphological operations to remove noise and fill in holes.
        mask = imopen(mask, strel('rectangle', [3,3]));
        mask = imclose(mask, strel('rectangle', [15, 15])); 
        mask = imfill(mask, 'holes');

        % Perform blob analysis to find connected components.
        [~, centroids, bboxes] = obj.blobAnalyser.step(mask);
    end

%% Predict New Locations of Existing Tracks

    function predictNewLocationsOfTracks()
        for i = 1:length(tracks)
            bbox = tracks(i).bbox;

            % Predict the current location of the track.
            predictedCentroid = predict(tracks(i).kalmanFilter);

            % Shift the bounding box so that its center is at 
            % the predicted location.
            predictedCentroid = int32(predictedCentroid) - bbox(3:4) / 2;
            tracks(i).bbox = [predictedCentroid, bbox(3:4)];
        end
    end

%% Assign Detections to Tracks

    function [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
            detectionToTrackAssignment()

        nTracks = length(tracks);
        nDetections = size(centroids, 1);

        % Compute the cost of assigning each detection to each track.
        cost = zeros(nTracks, nDetections);
        for i = 1:nTracks
            cost(i, :) = distance(tracks(i).kalmanFilter, centroids);
        end

        % Solve the assignment problem.
        costOfNonAssignment = 20;
        [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
            assignDetectionsToTracks(cost, costOfNonAssignment);
    end

%% Update Assigned Tracks

    function updateAssignedTracks()
        numAssignedTracks = size(assignments, 1);
        for i = 1:numAssignedTracks
            trackIdx = assignments(i, 1);
            detectionIdx = assignments(i, 2);
            centroid = centroids(detectionIdx, :);
            bbox = bboxes(detectionIdx, :);

            % Correct the estimate of the object's location
            % using the new detection.
            correct(tracks(trackIdx).kalmanFilter, centroid);

            % Replace predicted bounding box with detected
            % bounding box.
            tracks(trackIdx).bbox = bbox;

            % Update track's age.
            tracks(trackIdx).age = tracks(trackIdx).age + 1;

            % Update visibility.
            tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount = ...
                tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount + 1;
            tracks(trackIdx).consecutiveInvisibleCount = 0;
        end
    end

%% Update Unassigned Tracks
% Mark each unassigned track as invisible, and increase its age by 1.

    function updateUnassignedTracks()
        for i = 1:length(unassignedTracks)
            ind = unassignedTracks(i);
            tracks(ind).age = tracks(ind).age + 1;
            tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount = ...
                tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount + 1;
        end
    end

%% Delete Lost Tracks

    function deleteLostTracks()
        if isempty(tracks)
            return;
        end

        invisibleForTooLong = 20;
        ageThreshold = 8;

        % Compute the fraction of the track's age for which it was visible.
        ages = [tracks(:).age];
        totalVisibleCounts = [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount];
        visibility = totalVisibleCounts ./ ages;

        % Find the indices of 'lost' tracks.
        lostInds = (ages < ageThreshold & visibility < 0.6) | ...
            [tracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] >= invisibleForTooLong;

        % Delete lost tracks.
        tracks = tracks(~lostInds);
    end

%% Create New Tracks

    function createNewTracks()
        centroids = centroids(unassignedDetections, :);
        bboxes = bboxes(unassignedDetections, :);

        for i = 1:size(centroids, 1)

            centroid = centroids(i,:);
            bbox = bboxes(i, :);

            % Create a Kalman filter object.
            kalmanFilter = configureKalmanFilter('ConstantVelocity', ...
                centroid, [200, 50], [100, 25], 100);

            % Create a new track.
            newTrack = struct(...
                'id', nextId, ...
                'bbox', bbox, ...
                'kalmanFilter', kalmanFilter, ...
                'age', 1, ...
                'totalVisibleCount', 1, ...
                'consecutiveInvisibleCount', 0);

            % Add it to the array of tracks.
            tracks(end + 1) = newTrack;

            % Increment the next id.
            nextId = nextId + 1;
        end
    end

%% Display Tracking Results
% The |displayTrackingResults| function draws a bounding box and label ID 
% for each track on the video frame and the foreground mask. It then 
% displays the frame and the mask in their respective video players. 

    function displayTrackingResults()
        % Convert the frame and the mask to uint8 RGB.
        frame = im2uint8(frame);
        mask = uint8(repmat(mask, [1, 1, 3])) .* 255;

        minVisibleCount = 8;
        if ~isempty(tracks)

            % Noisy detections tend to result in short-lived tracks.
            % Only display tracks that have been visible for more than 
            % a minimum number of frames.
            reliableTrackInds = ...
                [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount] > minVisibleCount;
            reliableTracks = tracks(reliableTrackInds);

            % Display the objects. If an object has not been detected
            % in this frame, display its predicted bounding box.
            if ~isempty(reliableTracks)
                % Get bounding boxes.
                bboxes = cat(1, reliableTracks.bbox);

                % Get ids.
                ids = int32([reliableTracks(:).id]);

                % Create labels for objects indicating the ones for 
                % which we display the predicted rather than the actual 
                % location.
                labels = cellstr(int2str(ids'));
                predictedTrackInds = ...
                    [reliableTracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] > 0;
                isPredicted = cell(size(labels));
                isPredicted(predictedTrackInds) = {' predicted'};
                labels = strcat(labels, isPredicted);

                % Draw the objects on the frame.
                frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', ...
                    bboxes, labels);

                % Draw the objects on the mask.
                mask = insertObjectAnnotation(mask, 'rectangle', ...
                    bboxes, labels);
            end
        end

        % Display the mask and the frame.
        obj.maskPlayer.step(mask);        
        obj.videoPlayer.step(frame);
    end

end
```

Comment: Could you be specific on what's your problem?

Comment: i have edited the question, maybe it will be more clear now.The thing is that i have to base my code on the article i attached, and i don't expects people to read the article, so itried to summarize it.

Comment: Please do not deface your question, as that disrespects the effort others put into trying to answer it.

Comment: Do not edit the question this way. I don't understand your purpose. This community is for everybody's benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you would need to modify the `detectObjects` function with the code to eliminate shadows. Currently, all it does is it takes a foreground mask from background subtraction (`vision.ForegroundDetector`), removes some noise and fills in small gaps using morphology, and then it finds connected components, a.k.a. "blobs". Typically, the blobs do include shadows.

If your shadow removal algorithm operates on a single frame, than this is where the code for it would go.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your object detection. Your code is using an `imopen` and and `imclose`. But I think you want to use `imdilate` and `imerode`

```
%% Detect Objects

function [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame)

    % Detect foreground.
    mask = obj.detector.step(frame);

    % Apply morphological operations to remove noise and fill in holes.

    %this makes the white space smaller to remove small dots/noise
    mask = imerode(mask, strel('rectangle', [3,3]));

    %this makes the white regions larger to restore the original size
    mask = imclose(mask, strel('rectangle', [15, 15])); 

    mask = imfill(mask, 'holes');

    % Perform blob analysis to find connected components.
    [~, centroids, bboxes] = obj.blobAnalyser.step(mask);
end
```

I changed your `imopen` and `imclose` you may need to change your structuring elements as well. If you look at the [matlab documentation imopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) is the same as erosion followed by dilation, or `imopened = imdilate(imerode(im,se)));`
[Imclose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html) is dilation followed by erosion or `imcloseed = imerode(imdilate(im,se))`

the paper is using an erosion followed by a dilation (an imopen operation). So that is what I put in the code. If you want to use the same structuring element for both operations you can change

```
    %this makes the white space smaller to remove small dots/noise
    mask = imerode(mask, strel('rectangle', [3,3]));

    %this makes the white regions larger to restore the original size
    mask = imclose(mask, strel('rectangle', [15, 15]));
```

to

```
    mask = imopen(mask,strel('rectangle',[15 15]));
```

since you didn't include your pictures I can't try it out, but I think it should work after you play with your `strel` function

Comment: thank you, i did't even noticed that mistake.But my quastion was on something else,maybe i wasn't clear enough.I want to add a shadow removal algorithm to my code.and i can't include pictures because i'm new here,and you need reputation in order to include pictures.